# How to fix my algorithm to use week numbers to build a calendar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm, momentjs

I am writing an algorithm to generate the rows in a calendar.
The calendar is written in AngularJS and in JavaScript. I am also using momentJS to help.

For each month, I am building an array of weeks. The objects in the array map the week number to their corresponding year. I am doing it this way to easily display some data from the server.

e.g. March

```
[
    { week: 9, year: 2019 },
    { week: 10, year: 2019 },
    { week: 11, year: 2019 },
    { week: 12, year: 2019 },
    { week: 13, year: 2019 }
]
```

My algorithm works fine for most months e.g. Feb->Nov
However, December and January appear to be edge cases.

The last week of December can roll over into the next year and the first week of Jan can roll over into the previous year. My algorithm fails for the edge cases.

Here is the code:
https://codepen.io/aubz/pen/ROxKNY

For example, it fails for DEC 2018 and JAN 2017

Expected results:

```
[
    { week: 53, year: 2016 }, 
    { week: 1, year: 2017 }, 
    { week: 2, year: 2017 }, 
    { week: 3, year: 2017 },
    { week: 4, year: 2017 },
    { week: 5, year: 2017 }
]


[
    { week: 51, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 52, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 53, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 54, year: 2018 },
    { week: 1, year: 2019 }
]
```

Actual results:

DEC 2018

```
[
    { week: 51, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 52, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 53, year: 2018 }, 
    { week: 54, year: 2018 },
    { week: 1, year: 2018 }
]
JAN 2017 - completely wrong
0: {week: 1, year: 2017}
1: {week: 2, year: 2017}
2: {week: 3, year: 2017}
3: {week: 4, year: 2017}
4: {week: 5, year: 2017}
```

How can I fix my algorithm to accommodate the edge cases?

Here is my algorithm snippet:

```
var data = {};        
data.currentCalendarMonth = moment().startOf('month');

var result = buildListOfWeeksForCurrentMonth();

console.log(result);

function buildListOfWeeksForCurrentMonth() {

  data.weeks = [];

  //this could be in a different year
  var startOfMonthWeekNumber = data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().startOf('month').week();
  var endOfMonthWeekNumber = data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().endOf('month').week();

  console.log(' startOfMonthWeekNumber ', startOfMonthWeekNumber);
  console.log(' endOfMonthWeekNumber ', endOfMonthWeekNumber);

  var weeksHere = [];

  //TODO: end of year edge case
  if (startOfMonthWeekNumber > endOfMonthWeekNumber) {

      console.log(' edge cases for dec and jan ');

      var weeksInYear = moment().weeksInYear();

      console.log(' weeks in year ', weeksInYear);

      for (var k = startOfMonthWeekNumber; k < weeksInYear + 1; k++) {

          console.log(' week year ', data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().week(k).startOf('day').weekYear());

          weeksHere.push({
              week: k,
              year: data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().week(k).startOf('day').weekYear()
          });
      }

      for (var m = 1; m < endOfMonthWeekNumber + 1; m++) {

          console.log(' week year again ', data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().get('year'));

          weeksHere.push({
              week: m,
              year: data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().get('year')
          });
      }

    } else {

        console.log(' ususal case ');

        for (var i = startOfMonthWeekNumber; i < endOfMonthWeekNumber + 1; i++) {
            weeksHere.push({
                week: i,
                year: data.currentCalendarMonth.clone().week(i).startOf('day').weekYear()
            });
        }
    }

    console.log(' WEEKS ', weeksHere);

    return weeksHere;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post your actual results to compare with the expected results?

Comment: Get first day of year and go back to the previous sunday if not. Then add 7 days until you get out the concerned year.